How to make a customloss function with more variable inputs work
I am making or trying to make a model that can estimate intrinsic camera parameters. For this, I want to use a custom loss function that uses the estimated intrinsic camera parameters, and then undistoreds the image and compares it to a depth image (from the same location made from a lidar pointcloud). But the loss function gives the following error:
Node: 'gradient_tape/model/pose_loss_layer/undistort_layer/map/while/gradients/model/pose_loss_layer/undistort_layer/map/while/strided_slice_2_grad/StridedSliceGrad'
shape of dy was [] instead of [5]
         [[{{node gradient_tape/model/pose_loss_layer/undistort_layer/map/while/gradients/model/pose_loss_layer/undistort_layer/map/while/strided_slice_2_grad/StridedSliceGrad}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2727]

Here is the code that I use to test the loss function (this is only to test the loss function, in the other model I use more layers and everything, but this model gives the same error).
class UndistortLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UndistortLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        camera_images, intrinsic_params, distortion_coeffs = inputs

        def undistort_image(camera_image, intrinsic_params, distortion_coeffs):
            # Create intrinsic matrix
            intrinsic_matrix = create_intrinsic_matrix(intrinsic_params)

            # Undistort image using OpenCV
            undistorted_image = cv2.undistort(
                camera_image.numpy().astype(np.uint8),
                intrinsic_matrix,
                np.array(distortion_coeffs, dtype=np.float32)
            )
            return undistorted_image.astype(np.float32)

        # Apply the undistortion function using tf.py_function for each image
        undistorted_images = tf.map_fn(
            lambda i: tf.py_function(
                undistort_image,
                [camera_images[i], intrinsic_params[i], distortion_coeffs[i]],
                Tout=tf.float32
            ),
            tf.range(tf.shape(camera_images)[0]),  # Loop over the batch
            dtype=tf.float32
        )
        undistorted_images.set_shape([None, 480, 640, 3])
        return undistorted_images


class PoseLossLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        output_intrinsic, camera_input, depth_input = inputs
        
        camera_images = camera_input  # Shape: (batch_size, 480, 640, 3)
        depth_images = depth_input    # Shape: (batch_size, 480, 640)

        # Retrieve intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients from predictions
        intrinsic_params = output_intrinsic[..., :3]  # fx, cx, cy
        distortion_coeffs = output_intrinsic[..., 3:]  # distortion coefficients

        # Ensure UndistortLayer supports backpropagation
        undistorted_camera_images = UndistortLayer()([camera_images, intrinsic_params, distortion_coeffs])

        # Convert to grayscale correctly
        undistorted_camera_images_gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(undistorted_camera_images)

        # Calculate SSIM between undistorted camera images and depth images
        ssim_loss = tf.image.ssim(undistorted_camera_images_gray, depth_images, max_val=1.0)

        # Compute the mean SSIM loss to ensure a scalar is returned
        mean_ssim_loss = tf.reduce_mean(ssim_loss)

        # Return a scalar loss value for backpropagation
        return 1 - mean_ssim_loss


def create_model():
    # Define flexible input layers
    camera_input = Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name='camera_image')
    depth_input = Input(shape=(None, None, 1), name='depth_image')

    # Process depth image to have 3 channels
    depth_input_3ch = Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(x))(depth_input)

    # Concatenate camera and depth images
    concatenated_features = Concatenate(name='RGB_Depth_concatenate')([camera_input, depth_input_3ch])
    
    # Add Global Average Pooling to reduce spatial dimensions
    pooled_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(concatenated_features)

    # Dense layers
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(pooled_features)
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    output_intrinsic = Dense(8, activation='linear', name='intrinsic_parameters')(x)

    # PoseLossLayer to compute loss inside the graph
    pose_loss = PoseLossLayer()([output_intrinsic, camera_input, depth_input])

    # Define the model
    model = Model(inputs=[camera_input, depth_input], outputs=output_intrinsic)

    # Add loss to model
    model.add_loss(pose_loss)

    # Compile the model (without loss, as it's added via add_loss)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam')

    return model

model.fit(
    x=[camera_images_array, depth_images_array],
    y=Parameters_Short, 
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=5,
    callbacks=[CustomCallback()]
)

Hope anyone knows the problem or a better way to add the loss function.
tried to change the return format, tried to add it in the model.compile function but nothing works
